# Can't pass some fields from one method to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've tried to create a parser using python scrapy which is supposed to extract some fields from a webpage. The issue I'm facing here is that I can't pass the parameter in the right way to the "target_page" method in spider class. I know the way I passed "caption" and "value" fields from "parse" method to "target_page" is not at all pythonic. However, I did it cause I don't really have any idea how to pass the aforesaid fields in the "target_page" method in a proper way. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

```
import scrapy

class BrokerSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "brokersp"
    start_urls = ["https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/mt4/page{0}".format(page_num) for page_num in range(1,10)]

    def parse(self, response):
        for links in response.css("div#signals-table div.signal"):
            caption = links.css('span.name::text').extract_first()
            value = links.css('div.col-price::text').extract_first()
            link = links.css('a.signal-avatar::attr(href)').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(caption, value, url = link, callback = self.target_page)

    def target_page(self, title, price, response):
        jobber = response.css('div.header span a::text').extract_first()
        profit = response.css('div.cell.total a.blue::text').extract_first()
        yield {'title':title,'price':price,'jobber':jobber,'profit':profit}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `meta` attribute of the request ([documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions)):

```
def parse(self, response):
    for links in response.css("div#signals-table div.signal"):
        caption = links.css('span.name::text').extract_first()
        value = links.css('div.col-price::text').extract_first()
        link = links.css('a.signal-avatar::attr(href)').extract_first()
        request = scrapy.Request(url = link, callback = self.target_page)
        request.meta['caption'] = caption
        request.meta['value'] = value
        yield request

def target_page(self, response):
    caption = response.meta['caption']
    value = response.meta['value']
    jobber = response.css('div.header span a::text').extract_first()
    profit = response.css('div.cell.total a.blue::text').extract_first()
    yield {'title':caption,'price':value,'jobber':jobber,'profit':profit}
```

Comment: Thanks PRMoureu to care for a solution. I'm sending this text from my cell phone. As soon as I'm near my pc I'll give you the feedback. Thanks again.

Comment: @Shahin, good thing you haven't test yet, i just fixed something

Comment: You are the life-saver PRMoureu. Thanks a lot to give me the idea. Currently I'm not being able to run this particular script because of "403" status of that site from my server. However, if i encounter any problem executing your code later, I'll let you know. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I executed your rectified script and it ran just perfect. Thankssssss dear, PRMoureu.

Comment: Thanks for this nice feedback @Shahin